# OpenEvent/OpenFileMapping fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, synchronization, memory-mapped-files

I'm developing an open source .NET assembly ([WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)) that spawns a native (C++) application and communicates with it via events and file mapping objects.

The assembly spawns the application using the `Process` class, with no special settings. The assembly creates few events (using the `EventWaitHandle`) and file mapping (using the PInvoked `CreateFileMapping`) and the application "opens" these using the `OpenEvent` and the `OpenFileMapping`.

It works fine in most cases. But now I'm having a user that uses the assembly from an ASPX application on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit.

In his case both the `OpenEvent` and the `OpenFileMapping` return `NULL` and the `GetLastError` returns the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I have tried to improve the assembly code by explicitly granting the current user necessary permissions to the event objects and the application code to require only the really needed access rights (instead of original `EVENT_ALL_ACCESS`) as per [Microsoft Docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.eventwaithandlesecurity). It didn't help. So I did not even bother to try the same for the file mapping object.

The C# code that creates the event is:

```csharp
EventWaitHandleSecurity security = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();

string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;

EventWaitHandleAccessRule rule;
rule =
    new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(
        user, EventWaitHandleRights.Synchronize | EventWaitHandleRights.Modify,
        AccessControlType.Allow);
security.AddAccessRule(rule);
rule =
    new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(
        user, EventWaitHandleRights.ChangePermissions, AccessControlType.Deny);
security.AddAccessRule(rule);

new EventWaitHandle(
    false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, name, out createdNew, security);
```

The C++ code that "opens" the events is:

```c
OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, false, name);
```

(For other events the access level is `SYNCHRONIZE`, depending on needs).

I have also tried to add `Global\` prefix to the object names. As expected this didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what causes the "access denied" error in `OpenEvent` (or `CreateFileMapping`)?

Comment: Doubtful you an fix that, ASP.NET apps run by default with a limited user account.  Some [background here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood the scenario properly.  The problem may be that you are running under a restricted token, i.e., a process can be run in such a way that it doesn't have the complete access rights of the user account it is running as.  You might need to examine the security token to find out what SIDs are enabled in order to set permissions on the object appropriately; sorry, I'm not sure how to do that in .NET.  Another approach would be to arrange for the subprocess to inherit the existing object handles rather than opening new ones; again, no idea how you'd do that in .NET.

Comment: If the event and mapped file was created with an ACL that didn't allow everyone access, a restricted context like ASP.NET isn't likely to be able to open it.  I'd first suggest opening the event and mapped file with explicit rights for the user that the ASP.NET process runs under.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl create... See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595(v=vs.85).aspx for an example (Everyone) of creating the security descriptor of a security attribute structure.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: do you happen to know whether the Everyone SID is enabled or not for an ASPX application running with a restricted token?  I'm fairly sure the SID for the user account isn't going to be.  The best bet is the logon SID, but I'm not quite sure how you would go about extracting that SID from your token.

Comment: @HarryJohnston the Everyone group (or World group) is a well-know SID on Windows.  I'm not sure what a "disabled SID" means.  You wouldn't extract the SID from a token, it should be known when the code is written.  e.g. the code that creates the event uses a specific SID and the code that opens the event uses the same sid.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: see [CreateRestrictedToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446583(v=vs.85).aspx).  I'm speculating that ASPX uses restricted tokens - it would be sensible, after all - or that the relevant service is configured to use a restricted token.  If the service is SERVICE_SID_TYPE_RESTRICTED then the [Everyone (aka World) SID is indeed disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685987(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: In the case of a restricted service, I may be wrong but I don't think there's any well-known or otherwise predictable SID enabled in the token.  The only option is to extract the logon SID, which you can do by passing the TokenLogonSid option to GetTokenInformation.  (NB: my terminology was wrong, technically there are "restricting SIDs" and "deny-only SIDs" but not "disabled SIDs".)

Comment: Actually I might be reading that backwards and the Everyone SID *is* available; it isn't clear.  But you probably don't want to use Everyone anyway for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So in the .Net code, should I try `OpenProcessToken` for current process, pass that to `GetTokenInformation` and use the retrieved SID for the code from article *Creating a Security Descriptor for a New Object*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: sounds about right, yes.

Comment: After several tests, it looks like that environment does not have the logon SID. I'm giving this up. Thanks for all the help. I'm gonna close this question as it seems too narrow.

Comment: Inheriting the handles looks like a better deal, but you'd have to have some way of passing their numeric values to the native process your .Net code spawns (e.g. process start arguments). p/invoke `DuplicateHandle` to create an inheritable copy of your event handle.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the event is created by either the anonymous user or the logged in user depending on how the website is setup. But the sub-process is being launched with the base process user.  This can be checked by using process monitor and looking at the acl for the event handle to see who the creator is.  Then look at the sub process to see who it is running as.
If this is the case then you can update the acl on the event to include the base process.  In addition to this, you may still need to prefix with "global" to make sure that the event can be used across user boundaries.